# When 2 matrices commute and have the same rank?

Tags: matrices, matrix-rank

When 2 matrices commute and have the same rank?

I know that $AB = BA$ when:

1.$ A=B$.
2.Either $A=cI$ or $B=cI.$
3.$A$ and $B$ are both diagonal matrices.
4.There exists an invertible matrix $P$ such that $P^{-1}AP$ and $P^{-1}BP$ are both diagonal.
5.$A = cB.$
6.$A = cB^{-1}.$
7.$A = 0$ or $B = 0.$

But couldn't go further to find when $AB=BA$ and they both have the same rank.
Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT :

In case it would help to answer, I need to find all the pairs of matrices $(A, B)$ that respect the following equations $AB = aA + bB$, where $A, B$ are 2 matrices and $a, b ∈ C^*.$ My hypothesis was that these 2 must first commute and have the same rank in order to respect the equations.

Comment: What kind of condition do you need ? I don't think you can get a simpler condition than "commuting and having the same rank".

Comment: I need to find pairs of matrices that respect the following equations $AB = aA + bB$, where A, B are 2 matrices and a, b are 2 real numbers. My hypothesis was that these 2 must first commute and have the same rank in order to respect the equations.

Comment: If $A=0$ and $b=0$, then for any matrix $B$, you have $AB=aA+bB$, so $A$ and $B$ don't have necessarily the same rank.

Comment: Sorry, $a, b$ needs to be from $C*$, forgot to specify this!

Comment: Did you try to use the Kronecker produc property to matrix equations? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Matrix_equations

Comment: @JoséCFerreira Could please help w an approach w the Kronecker product?

Comment: I will try to write in Latex and  post later.

Comment: @JoséCFerreira Thank you very much!

Comment: You can simplify your question by substituting $C=b^{-1}A$ and $D=a^{-1}B.$ Then
$CD=C+D.$

Comment: I was thinking on this: If $$AB=\alpha A+\beta B$$, you can use vectorization and Kronecher product properties to write this as
$$(I\otimes A) vec(B)=\alpha \,vec(A)+\beta\, vec(B)$$ or $$
(I\otimes A-\beta I\otimes I) vec(B)=\alpha \,vec(A).$$ If you choose $A$, $\alpha$ and $\beta$ you can try to find $B$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $C=b^{-1}A$ and $D=a^{-1}B.$ Then
$CD=C+D$ and
$C(D-I)=D.$ Thus
$\ker (D-I)\subset \ker D.$ Hence $\ker(D-I)=\{0\},$
i.e. $D-I$ is invertible and consequently $C=D(D-I)^{-1}.$ Therefore $C$ and $D$ commute and their ranks coincide.

Summarizing the equation $CD=C+D$ admits solutions of the form $C$ and $D,$ where $D$ is any matrix so that  $D-I$ is invertible and $C=D(D-I)^{-1}.$

In terms of $A$ and $B,$ the matrix $B-aI$ must be invertible and $A=bB(B-aI)^{-1}.$

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: You welcome. I have discovered another simpler solution. We have $(A-bI)(B-aI)=abI.$ Therefore both $A-bI$ and $B-aI$ are invertible and $A-bI=ab(B-aI)^{-1}.$ Therefore $A$ and $B$ commute.